# Is the projective linear group $PGL(3,\mathbb{R})$ a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have never come across a statement that it is a Lie group, although
the group has 8 one-parametric subgroups  and we can asign to $PGL(3,\mathbb{R})$ a Lie algebra.

So, is the $PGL(3,\mathbb{R})$  a Lie group  and what is a connection between $PGL(3,\mathbb{R})$ and the above mentioned Lie algebra?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know/understand why 'ordinary' $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ (without the $P$) is a Lie group?

Comment: the group operation in $GL(3)$ is  continious?

Comment: what about the second part of question?  What is a Lie group related to the Lie algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already know that $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group. $PGL(3, \mathbb{R})$ is a quotient of $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ by the subgroup $\mathbb{R}^*$ sitting inside $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ as the scalar multiples of the identity.

The interesting *general question* here is then: suppose we know that $G$ is a s Lie group and $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, how 'well-behaved' must $H$ be in order for the quotient $G/H$ to be a Lie group as well?

I hope some other commenter with more time can answer this general question. However for $GL(3, \mathbb{R})$ or more general $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ with $n$ odd we are in a *very special case* where $H$ is not just well-behaved but *very well behaved*: here the scalar multiples of the identity are not just a normal subgroup but a factor in a direct product:

$$GL(3, \mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^* \times SL(3, \mathbb{R})$$

It is easy to see that this group isomorphism is continuous, so it is not just an isomorphism of groups but also of Lie groups.

As a result we have that $PGL(3, \mathbb{R}) \cong SL(3, \mathbb{R})$ both as a group and as a manifold.

So in this case it is much easier to check that $PGL(3, \mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group: we can just check it for $SL(3, \mathbb{R})$, which is easy since it is 'concrete' with 'actual' elements that are matrices rather than 'abstact' in the sense of 'the quotient of something else'.

Subsequently the Lie algebra of $PGL(3, \mathbb{R})$ is the same as the Lie algebra of $SL(3, \mathbb{R})$. Usually this Lie algebra is denoted $\mathfrak{sl}(3, \mathbb{R})$ and represented as the set of all 3-by-3 trace zero matrices.

In a sense the question whether $PGL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group is more interesting for even $n$: the answer is still yes, but the reason is more subtle.

Comment: Thank you! Nice explanation

Comment: Quotient of a Lie group by a closed subgroup is always a manifold. Thus, if the subgroup is normal then the quotient is a Lie group. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221222/let-g-be-a-lie-group-how-to-prove-that-g-h-is-a-manifold).

Comment: hi! @Moishe Kohan
 is it enough to say that $GL_n(R)$ is a lie-group and $Z$ is a normal subgroup so the quotient is also a li-group? and the dim of $PGL_n(R)$ is $diim GL_n(r)-dim Z=n^2-1$

Comment: @user652838: As I said, you have to assume that the normal subgroup is closed. I will leave it to you to work out a counter-example if this is not the case.